# Sort an Array using integer in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a text file in which there are many lines as:

```
name age address
```

I am taking the value of each line as

```
Array myArray = line.split(" ");
```

where line is red from the buffer reader.

Now i want to sort the array according to descending age and using below:

`Arrays.sort(myArray)` however its not working

Comment: be more specific, paste array creation an population

Comment: Why do you think your code should work? Which part of documentation makes you think so?

Comment: put content of your array into your question. Also, you need to have an implementation of sorting

Comment: what do you mean by `array of 5 columns`? Do you mean you have an array of your custom type, which contains 5 different elements in it. Please provide that information as well.

Comment: I would suggest you read about `String.split()`, `ArrayList` and `Arrays.sort()` for solving your problem. You need to store all the elements from a line in separate variable or custom class type.

Comment: I think people are over reacting on this question. The OP has edited the question and it is clear what he is asking. I voted to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a class to hold your data:

```
public class DataRow {
    private String mName;
    private int mAge;
    private String mAddress;

    public DataRow(String mName, int mAge, String mAddress) {
        this.mName = mName;
        this.mAge = mAge;
        this.mAddress = mAddress;
    }

    public String  getRow() {
        return mName + "\t" + mAge + "\t" + mAddress;
    }

    //Optional
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getRow();
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return mAge;
    }
}
```

A simple test in console:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<DataRow> mData = new ArrayList<>();
        mData.add(new DataRow("Saeid", 28, "blabla"));
        mData.add(new DataRow("Alice", 23, "blablablaaa"));
        mData.add(new DataRow("Frederiek", 26, "blasasaasasasas"));

        //You have to define your own comparator for the DataRow object
        //For descending it will be like this:
        mData.sort(new Comparator<DataRow>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(DataRow o1, DataRow o2) {
                return o1.getAge() - o2.getAge();
            }
        });

        System.out.println("NAME\tAGE\tADDRESS");
        for(DataRow dr:mData) {
            System.out.println(dr.getRow());
        }
}
```

Here is the result:

```
NAME    AGE ADDRESS
Alice   23  blablablaaa
Frederiek   26  blasasaasasasas
Saeid   28  blabla
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis my pervious answer was befor OP edited his question

Comment: Awesome, now I suggest you don't encourage poor questions like this by answering them.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I myself started with poor questions like this, and thanks to people who answered I got a bit improved over time!

Comment: Your programming _may_ have improved, sure. The point is to improve contributions to Stack Overflow. Answering these questions does not do that.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis While you might be right, I am sure SO has its own methods to maintain its quality. If such questions would be pointless to SO, there might exist ways implemented by SO to remove/purge such question.

Comment: Yes, downvote and vote to close/delete. Don't answer. If you're going to be part of SO, you should use its methods to remove/purge, if you haven't already.